# Leverage browser caching (chrome audit)

Tags: caching, browser, localhost, audit

im trying to learn about browser caching techniques.
all is going good so far, apart from one bit im stuck on.
when i run an audit on google chrome. i get

```
Leverage browser caching (1)
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:
www.noelie.localhost.com/
```

i fixed the css and javascript with

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|jpg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536050, public, cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

how do i cache the homepage www.noelie.localhost.com.
thank you for your time. noelie